# Java compiler version for Maven build of a Spring Boot product

Tags: spring-boot

[Here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-maven), it says that Spring Boot 1.5.2.RELEASE requires Java 7 or later; 
and Java 1.6 as the default compiler level.

So would this difference cause an issue?

Comment: I think there is no issue because:
(my env)JDK1.8 > JAVA7(Spring Boot requires) > 1.6 (my classes compiled). But what if (my env)JDK1.8 with JAVA7(Spring Boot requires) with 1.8 (my classes compiled)?

Comment: It won't cause a problem since Spring Boot 1.5.2.RELEASE requires Java 7 or **later**

Comment: Does what you said means Spring Boot 1.5.2.RELEASE is compiled with Java 7? and same is the builtin tomcat. can classes compiled with Java 8 run in tomcat compiled with Java 7?

Comment: You are confusing everything, it says spring boot supports 1.7 and upwards, so you shouldn't worry about their code, just worry about your own compatibility, and use 1.7 or higher to be able to use spring boot, that is all

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can specify the JDK for the Maven build by using the following plugin;

[Apache Maven Compiler Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/).

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.6.1</version>
          <configuration>
            <source>1.7</source>
            <target>1.7</target>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

Trying to compile Java1.7 code with JDK 1.6 would indeed cause issues.

Also you can use `java.version` property to specify your Java version, as described [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-maven-java-version), you can see the usage of `maven-compiler-plugin` on the `spring-boot-parent` pom.xml, [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.5.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-parent/pom.xml#L521)

Thanks to [Brandon Mintern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42802712/java-compiler-version-for-maven-build-of-a-spring-boot-product/42802887#42802887), and [M.Deinum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42802712/java-compiler-version-for-maven-build-of-a-spring-boot-product/42802788#comment72721650_42802788)

Comment: You don't need that plugin as that is already provided by Spring Boot. You only need to set the `java.version` property or the `maven.compiler.source` and `maven.compiler.target` properties. No need to explicitly add the plugin for that.

Answer (score 11):

It is practically always safe to use a newer version of the compiler than what the code was compiled with. The reverse is not always true.

In addition to [bureaquete's suggestion to configure the Apache Maven Compiler Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42802788/1237044), you may also be able to override the version in the properties section of your POM:

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

In order for this to work, you will need to have Java 7 installed and configured correctly.

Answer (score 0):

solution if you are using Maven on Eclipse IDE is to set the correct JDK in your Maven configuration:

On your Eclipse IDE, Click on Run As… -> Run Configurations…
Select your Maven Build or create a new one
And on the JRE tab, check in the Runtime JRE section that you are using the correct JDK. If not, click Installed JREs… and add the adequate one.
Click Apply

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow.  I downvoted your answer, because it's not clear if this will update the Maven pom.xml.  If it's just a way to get Eclipse to use the correct JDK, but it doesn't fix command-line Maven builds, then your answer doesn't answer the original question.  I hope this helps!